# npm modules versioning on popper.js sample: why 1.13.0 is not a release?

Tags: npm, version, bootstrap-4

`npm view popper.js versions` returns  this list of versions

[... 
  '1.12.8',
  '1.12.9',
  '1.13.0-next',
  '1.13.0' ]

But the current popper.js version is 1.12.9 :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js
[image]

Could somebody help me to understand what is a 1.13.0  ? Is it a prerelease ? Hidden version?

P.S. I'm trying to find the way how to get a last prerelease version of bootstrap with the npm, I understand that I should write a script around `npm view popper.js versions` but there is a sample of output that I can't interpretate.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should ask your question about Popper.js here : https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js

Comment: I mean I do not understand is it a common thing around npm that "current version" is not a latest release? This and the fact that I can't get the list of availabl updates (including betas) in one npm command makes me crazy. Why it is done this way? There should be an explanation of it.

Comment: Yep I don't understand either, that's why I suggested to ask the creator of Popper.js